# Test fails duing run all tests, but running them one by one successes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, simple-injector

I have 4 tests spread across 3 test classes. If I run each test one by one they all can succeed. But running all (parallel I think?) they all fail except the first one fired?

My tests require the same setup, so I have a fixture which all tests are set up with:

```
public class CompositionRootFixture
{
    public Container Container { get; private set; } // Simple Injector Container

    public CompositionRootFixture()
    {
        Container = new Container();

        /* code removed for clearity */

        Container.Verify();
    }
}
```

And is used in my test classes like so:

```
public class CommandProcessorTests : IClassFixture<CompositionRootFixture>
{
    private readonly CompositionRootFixture _fixture;

    public CommandProcessorTests(CompositionRootFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestExecutingUsingContainerForResolution()
    {
        var commands = _fixture.Container.GetInstance<IExecuteCommands>();
        var command = new FakeCommandWithoutValidator();
        await commands.Execute(command);

        Assert.Equal("faked", command.ReturnValue);
    }
}
```

I have a hard time figuring out how to use the `IClassFixture<T>` and the documentation is not very helpful in setting this up. I am using the latest XUnit 2.0.0-beta5-build2785.

Failed description:

```
---- System.InvalidOperationException : The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IHandleCommand<FakeCommandWithoutValidator> failed. The registered delegate for type IHandleCommand<FakeCommandWithoutValidator> threw an exception. The configuration is invalid. The type HandleFakeCommandWithoutValidator is directly or indirectly depending on itself.
-------- SimpleInjector.ActivationException : The registered delegate for type IHandleCommand<FakeCommandWithoutValidator> threw an exception. The configuration is invalid. The type HandleFakeCommandWithoutValidator is directly or indirectly depending on itself.
------------ SimpleInjector.ActivationException : The configuration is invalid. The type HandleFakeCommandWithoutValidator is directly or indirectly depending on itself.
---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: CompositionRootFixture fixture
```

Comment: In my experience, the container's verification is almost never wrong. So if it says that "HandleFakeCommandWithoutValidator is directly or indirectly depending on itself", it probably is. Take a good look at your configuration, since cyclic dependencies are a bad thing. Even without using a container. If it only fails sometimes, might it be the case that you configure the container differently per test?

Comment: Running them one by one does not make them fail, only if I run them with the xunit run all action. I will have to look into how the container is configured. Maybe dispose it after every test or completely remove my fixture and set it up in each test.

Comment: @meep are you able to reproduce this in a simple project and upload that project to the [simple injector forum](https://simpleinjector.org/forum)?

Comment: Yes, I believe I can. I need to get off work first and get back home, but I'll post it once its done - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this question by upgrading to xUnit 2.0.0 and using the new Collection Fixture, which is described on their website: http://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html

Answer (score 3):

Your container is leveraging a singleton which maintains state throughout the duration of the all tests being executed.

Initialize this singleton before each test.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be related to a bug in SimpleInjector:

http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/259167

In any case, the problem is with the dependency injection.  If that bug isn't fixed, you might try a different IoC container like Ninject, at least for comparison.

Comment: The page you referring at describes a problem that existed in the documentation's code samples years ago in v1, that -as you can see in that thread- got fixed in May 2011. So I find it very unlikely that this problem has persisted after all these years, especially since the test coverage that exists for this the ASP.NET integration package and the amount of developers that use this package on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue with my scenario (some integration tests running tests against an EventStore) although I am not using a ClassFixture.

The idea of xUnit testing is that it can run each Fact in parallel. If you want to avoid that you can add the following on some of your assembly classes

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```

and they'll run sequentially.

**NOTE:**
Ideally this should be avoided because there's great interest in designing your tests and code in a way that it's idempotent and stateless, in fact I use all my tests as a subclass of this, to have a nice Given Then When structure:

```
public abstract class Given_When_Then_Test
    : IDisposable
{
    protected Given_When_Then_Test()
    {
        Setup();
    }

    private void Setup()
    {
        Given();
        When();
    }

    protected abstract void Given();

    protected abstract void When();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cleanup();
    }

    protected virtual void Cleanup()
    {
    }
}
```

Things I've discovered:

1. I have experienced errors in the integration tests running in parallel when I use `IContainer` of Autofac to resolve services instead resolving first `IComponentContext` and then resolving my services with it.

Comment: This is another question I've opened for my issue, which is similar in the way that parallel execution of xUnit causes always one test to fail:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254916/could-not-load-type-castle-proxies-ireadinessproxy-when-running-xunit-integratio

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone, but I had to ensure every Unit/Integration Test Project was referencing Xunit directly as a Nuget package. I thought it was enough to have a base test project and reference Xunit through that. Turns out this leads to many problems like inconclusive tests or tests running successfully but failing in parallel.